# Store data both in base and derived tables in Table-per-type inheritance in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to have the following tables:

```
Base
  Id
  Value1

Derived
  Id
  Value1
  Value2
```

`Value1` column should be stored both in `Base` and `Derived` tables, having equal values in both tables (this is done to speed up some specific queries).

Is it possible to archive this in Entity Framework?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Comment: I do not want to use Table-per-hierarchy inheritance.

Comment: Read on, it's a series of articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DbContext's OnModelCreating override, use the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Base>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("Base");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Derived>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Derived");
        });            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, never used `MapInheritedProperties` - now I know why it is there